# Attach to multiple events with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 project with Caliburn.Micro and I want to attach to 2 separate events on the same button.

What is the syntax for doing this?

I have tried a few combinations of the below but keep getting an error from Caliburn saying "Hop pair not part of existing route"

```
cm:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [Action SelectItem], [Event Hold] = [Action OpenItemMenu]"
```

So far I have been able to get it working with 1 event using the short syntax and one using the long but would prefer to be able to use them both the same way.

Comment: Just in case - in Windows Phone 8.1 the event name is [Holding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding), not _Hold_. _Hold_ is name of interaction gesture.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The delimiter for specifying multiple actions is a semicolon  `;`

```
<Button Content="Let's Talk" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter] = [Action Talk('Hello', Name.Text)]; [Event  MouseLeave] = [Action Talk('Goodbye', Name.Text)]" />
```